# Jquery hide function inside a class method fails IE

Tags: jquery, user-interface, internet-explorer-8, hide, show

I have written a javascript module (div object) which slides inside the document from right if you click inside an input element with using Jquery UI show and hide functions. This works properly in most of the browsers except IE 8.

The problem is that when the module hides itself, IE 8 won't open it anymore.

With a lot of work I managed to figure out some strangeness. When I run the following code as an onclick function of a button element to hide the module, then I can open it again.

```
$('#segitseg').hide('drop', { direction: 'right' }, 600);
```

But if I call the same line from an object, called Segitseg (it means help in English) like this:

```
var Segitseg = new function () {
    ...
    this.bezar = function() {
        $('#segitseg').hide('drop', { direction: 'right' }, 600);
    }
    ...
}
```

then I can't reopen the module again.

But I should have use the second variation, because the method bezar should make other things too.

Have anyone met this problem?

Comment: Why does the code only show calls to `hide()`, where are the calls to `show()`?

Comment: How do you try to open it? Please show more of your code, and consider creating a demo at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Hi! it's something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fSaPM/4/ by the way in my IE8 the jsfiddle site also falls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've found the problem!**

Well, when you call hide() on an element then it will change its opacity, or what is more important its alpha opacity, which is used by IE8. So the element will be just invisible.

**The solution:** (changing back the opacity after the hide() function ends)

```
$('#segitseg').hide('drop', { direction: 'right' }, 600, function(){
    $('#segitseg').css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=100)');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using : `$(document).ready(function() {});`